# IOS/Unity - Admob ads show impressions but ad is not visible?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm new Unity trying to put ads in my game. I want to place an interstitial ad at the start of a particular scene, and have followed this guide to do so: https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start

I integrated according to that guide, then the game on an actual device. While I don't see any ads, I checked in my Admob account, and did see counts for the impressions as expected. This leads me to believe that perhaps some sort of stacking order is incorrect, and maybe the ad is being shown behind the content of the scene? I'm not sure how I would go about testing and fixing this is that's the case, or even if that is a correct assumption.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite well experienced with Admob.

> ads show impressions but ad is not visible?

There could be multiple reasons why this happens. I will enumerate those I remember:

1. The real ads only show up in some countries.
2. There's no available ads (yet) to be shown in your location.
3. Layout might need to be corrected (especially if it's a native ad).

The #3 is less likely to be the reason.

> I'm not sure how I would go about testing and fixing this is that's
>   the case, or even if that is a correct assumption.

1. You can always use test ads.
2. You can use VPN to set your location to other countries if you're using a simulator. For example, I have a project before that had a similar issue, and I had to use VPN to set my location to Canada, U.S, or Singapore to get ads for testing.

I hope this helps!